# {COMPLEX} Nested structure pointers - SegFault when I use functions in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I am making a simple FileSystem. And I get segmentation fault. I tried valgrined with --leak-check=full but I don't know if any of my pointers are wrong or not.

```
Exemple input in [terminal]:
create fs
touch 123.c text
touch game.c anyText
delete fs
```

file.c file

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "file.h"

void createFS(Directory* myFileSystem);
void readString(char* operationToBeExecuted);

void append(struct Files** head_ref, char *name, char *data) 
{ 
    /* 1. allocate node */
    struct Files* new_list = (struct Files*)malloc(sizeof(struct Files)); 
    new_list->oneFile = malloc(sizeof(*(new_list->oneFile)));
    new_list->oneFile->name = malloc(sizeof(*(new_list->oneFile->name)));
    new_list->oneFile->data = malloc(sizeof(*(new_list->oneFile->data)));

    struct Files *last = *head_ref;  /* used in step 5*/

    /* 2. put in the data  */
    new_list->oneFile->name = strdup(name);
    new_list->oneFile->data = strdup(data);
    new_list->oneFile->size = strlen(data); 

    /* 3. This new node is going to be the last node, so make next of it as NULL*/
    new_list->next = NULL; 

    /* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the new node as head */
    if (*head_ref == NULL) 
    { 
       *head_ref = new_list; 
       return; 
    } 

    /* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
    while (last->next != NULL) 
        last = last->next; 

    /* 6. Change the next of last node */
    last->next = new_list; 
    return; 
} 

int main() {
    char *operationToBeExecuted = (char*)malloc(101 * sizeof(char));
    printf("What to do now?\n");
    readString(operationToBeExecuted);

    while (strcmp(operationToBeExecuted, "create fs") != 0) {
        printf("Please type \"create fs\" to create your FileSystem!\n");

        readString(operationToBeExecuted);
    }

    // Create our Parent Directory 
    Directory* Directory = NULL;
    Directory = (struct Directory*)malloc(sizeof(struct Directory));
    createFS(Directory);

    readString(operationToBeExecuted);
    while(strcmp(operationToBeExecuted, "") == 0) {
        printf("Please enter a Proper Value!\n");
        readString(operationToBeExecuted);
    }
    while (strcmp(operationToBeExecuted, "delete fs") != 0) {

        char *tempString = strtok(operationToBeExecuted, " ");

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (strcmp(tempString, "touch") == 0) {

            char *fileName = strtok(NULL, " ");
            char *content = strtok(NULL, " ");
            int lenght = strlen(content);

            Directory->Files = malloc(sizeof(*(Directory->Files)));

            append(&Directory->Files, fileName, content);

            printf("%s - ", Directory->Files->oneFile->name); // test
            printf("%s - ", Directory->Files->oneFile->data); // test
            printf("%d\n", Directory->Files->oneFile->size); // test
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
        } else if (strcmp(tempString, "mkdir") == 0) {
            printf("Wow. Let;s MKDIR!\n");
        } else {
            printf("Invalid operator! Please enter again!\n");
        }
        readString(operationToBeExecuted);
    }

    printf("You have successfully deleted your FileSystem!\n");
    free(operationToBeExecuted);
    free(Directory->Files->oneFile->name);
    free(Directory->Files->oneFile->data);
    free(Directory->Files->oneFile);
    free(Directory->Files);
    free(Directory);
}

void createFS(Directory* myFileSystem) {
    myFileSystem->name = malloc(sizeof(*(myFileSystem->name)));
    myFileSystem->parentDir = malloc(sizeof(*(myFileSystem->parentDir)));
    myFileSystem->name = "/";
    myFileSystem->parentDir = NULL;
    printf("%s\n", myFileSystem->name); // test
}

void readString(char* operationToBeExecuted) {
    fgets(operationToBeExecuted, 101, stdin);
    operationToBeExecuted[strlen(operationToBeExecuted) - 1] = '\0';
}
```

file.h file

```
#ifndef __FILE_H__
#define __FILE_H__


typedef struct Directory {
    // The name of the directory
    char *name;

    // TODO: The list of files of the current directory
    struct Files {
        struct File *oneFile;
        struct Files *next;
    } *Files;

    // TODO: The list of directories of the current directory
    struct Directories {
        struct Directory *oneDirectory;
        struct Directories *next;
    } *Directories;

    // The parent directory of the current directory (NULL for the root directory)
    struct Directory *parentDir;
} Directory;

// DO NOT MODIFY THIS STRUCTURE
typedef struct File {
    // The name of the file
    char *name;

    // The size of the file
    int size;

    // The content of the file
    char *data;

    // The directory in which the file is located
    Directory *dir;
} File;

#endif /* __FILE_H__ */
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Perhaps add asserts checking for null pointers.

Comment: if(!pointer) { printf("ThisIsWrong");}     Like this?

Comment: Just `assert(pointer != NULL);` or even `assert(pointer);`. Also `#include <assert.h>`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error#Assertions

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(*(new_list->oneFile->name)));` : ->name is a pointer to character. Dereferencing it with `*` results in a character. `sizeof(char)` is 1. (and the `new_list->oneFile->name = strdup(name);` reassigns to the pointer, causing a one byte memory leak)

Comment: `malloc(21 * sizeof(*(new_list->oneFile->name)))`